# How to delete file within catch block

Tags: java, file

```
public class deleteFile {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        StringBuffer fileNameStr = new StringBuffer();
        fileNameStr.append("c:/");
        fileNameStr.append("Test");
        File file = new File(fileNameStr.toString());

        String systemDateTime = null;
        try {
            systemDateTime = con.getSystemDateTime();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            file.delete();
        }
    }

}
```

According to this code, when I get `SQLException`, it can't delete file. Why?

Comment: does file exist !!. if exist then u have to set extention and path propertly i.e. c:\\test.{anyextension}

Comment: Shouldn't `c:/` be `c:\ `?

Comment: File creation case is ok. When catching exception, file deletion case is not ok.

Comment: @Atri you cannot use C:\ in double quotes you have to use "C:\\"

Comment: @AshishAni right, but I meant we need to use back slash instead of forward slash after `c:`

Comment: ok @Atri double quote is normally used

Comment: @Atri Not in Java. You can always use a forward slash.

Comment: This code does not compile, and if it did there is nothing to indicate it wouldn't execute as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about deleting a file in a catch block.

If your code (above) is not deleting the file, then it could be a number of things:

1. You may have the file pathname incorrect.
2. The file may not exist in the first place.
3. Your application may not have permission to delete the file, due to normal file / directory permission issues, "mandatory access control" restrictions (e.g. SELinux) or Java sandbox restrictions.
4. The file may be undeletable because it is "in use" ... on Windows.
5. That particular exception may not be being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Your catch block with SqlException never catching.
Use finally{} block in order to delete file or free resource.

Answer (score -1):

Actually my full source code is,

```
public class deleteFile {       
    public static void main(String args[]){            
        -------------------------                     
        StringBuffer fileNameStr = new StringBuffer();
        fileNameStr.append(.....);
        fileNameStr.append(.....);
        File file = new File(fileNameStr.toString());
       PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file),
                                "windows-31j")));
        String systemDateTime = null;
        try {
            systemDateTime = con.getSystemDateTime();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            file.delete();
        } 
        }
```

Finally I found the solution that is need to close printWriter before deletion file. Thank you for your advice.

```
try {
                    systemDateTime = con.getSystemDateTime();
                } catch (SQLException e) { 
                    printWriter.flush();
                    printWriter.close();
                    file.delete();}
        }
```

Comment: What PrintWriter? There isn't one mentioned in your question.